# Angularjs directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the code below the ng-show hides the text but never shows back the message. The angularjs is linked and the data-binding is working but ng-show and ng-disabled with condition don't work. Please tell me if you see a problem below.

```
     <from name="myProduct" class="main" ng-app="myProduct"  novalidate>


<div class="inputbox">
    <div class="boxtit">First Name</div>
    <div style="width: 100%;display: block">
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-ctl" placeholder="" ng-required="true" ng-model="tit">
<span ng-show="myProduct.title.$invalid && myProduct.title.$touched" class="errormess">There's an error</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need change `<from>` for `<form>`.

This a error OSI 8...

Example(fix):

```
<form name="myProduct" class="main" ng-app="myProduct"  novalidate>
    <div class="inputbox">
        <div class="boxtit">First Name</div>
        <div style="width: 100%;display:block">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-ctl" ng-required="true" ng-model="tit" />
            <span ng-show="myProduct.title.$invalid && myProduct.title.$touched" class="errormess">There's an error</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know how I couldnt find it. Sometimes someone else need to have a look on your code to find such an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo - `<from`. Fix it and it should start working. I don't see any problems beside it.